# Possible to have iOS Navigation Bar Button Item disabled and highlighted?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to have a UIBarButtonItem that is disabled (non-interactive) as well as highlighted.  My desire is to have a status icon in the NavBar, so I want it to be highlighted (not gray), but at the same time I don't want it to be a button.  Can you add things besides UIBarButtonItems to a NavBar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can!
Besides the name, UIBarButtonItem is not necessarily a button. You can add an image or anything else you want.

There's a initWithCustomView constructor where you can pass any view as parameter. For example:

```
UIImageView *statusImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"status"]];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: statusImageView];
```

If you want a clickable status, you can put the ImageView inside the UIButton.